# 403 forbidden error in the admin panel as well as on the admin-ajax.php file

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin, apache

I am using WordPress, My website was working perfectly until I changed the file permission.

**admin-ajax.php** is showing **403 forbidden** error and the rest of the file is working.

due to a 403 error, My website is completely down and now I am not able to understand what permission I have to set for this file. I have tried 777,755,644,640 but still I am getting 403 error

[image]

I thought let me login in admin panel and deactivate the plugin but my admin panel is showing like below image. But, I am 100% sure there is no issue with the plugin. I have deleted the htaccess file and added the new one but still same issue

[image]

I have added the below code in the wp-config.php file and it's showing perfectly but if I click on any of the menus like, plugin, setting, tool, post, or pages, all the pages are showing **403 forbidden**

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

Any idea what permission I have to set? I am using an AWS server.

Comment: Are you able to solve it? Facing same issue.

Comment: @krishnaisdinesh, Yes, there might be a folder permission issue. Kindly check it once